# Missing special characters with txfonts and XeLaTex in bibliography

Tags: xetex, characters

Special characters like "ń" and "ł" aren't shown in bibliography. I checked the raw logs and found it:

- Missing character: There is no ł ("142) in font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1!
- Missing character: There is no ń ("144) in font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1!

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Wierzchon2018,
    author =    {Wierzcho{\'n}, S{\l}awomir T. and K{\l}opotek, Mieczys{\l}aw A.},
    title =     {Modern Algorithms of Cluster Analysis},
    series =    {Studies in Big Data},
    number =    {34},
    year =      {2018},
    publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
    address =   {Cham},
    isbn =      {978-3-319-69308-8},
    doi =       {10.1007/978-3-319-69308-8},
    url =       {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-69308-8},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Correct:
Wierzcho{\'n} and K{\l}opotek \parencite{Wierzchon2018}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't replicate the issue you've encountered. Please tell us which TeX distribution and which version of the `biblatex` package you employ. (FWIW, on my MacTeX2021 system, all updates applied, i get the information that I'm using `biblatex 2020/12/31 v3.16`.)

Comment: I'm using XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 and biblatex: blx-case-expl3 2020/12/31 v3.16 expl3.

Comment: There's no problem for me with the full installation of TeX Live 2021.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you load the `fontspec` package instead of the `fontenc` package?

Comment: The problem appears only when I use txfonts together with XeTex. If I use fontspec after these fonts there will be no problem, but the text doesn't appear with the font that I want.

Comment: What happens if you load the `fontspec` package *before* running `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}`?

Comment: You shouldn't use T1-encoding with xelatex.

Comment: the xetex version is not relevant, but you need a rather current newtxtext, older version didn't support xelatex. It works for me with newtxtext 2022/01/11 v1.705 from texlive 2021.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was the older version. I was first using overleaf, then miketext and finally I installed tex live and everithing is okay. Thanks.