# Polish Ł, ł render as plain L, l using newtxtext

Tags: fonts, newtx

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}
á \L \l
\end{document}
```

(the `á` was there just for to test Unicode support). The output:

[image]

After commenting out the `newtxtext` import, I get:

[image]

Is there any workaround for this?

I tried to search the site for recent questions on the topic, and I found [this unanswered one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/631995/69595), but it is not quite the same problem, since there the chars are simply not rendered, and in my case they are replaced.

I'm running with the following specs:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an apparent bug in the OT1 encoded fonts of `newtxtext` that lack the slash in slot 32.

Use the T1 encoding, that's better anyway (for instance, Ł and ł are precomposed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

á \L \l

\textit{á \L \l}

\textbf{á \L \l}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Though I've been using LaTeX for years, the “T1” stuff was always mysterious to me. Is it in the same category of “utf8 encoding” but different? Could you point me to some basic docs on that?

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf T1 has many precomposed accented characters, supporting a lot of European languages; conversely, with the OT1 legacy encoding, combinations such as `á` would be copied as two separate glyphs; with T1 it's a single one; another benefit is on hyphenation.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf [What is the difference between font encoding and input encoding? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6448/what-is-the-difference-between-font-encoding-and-input-encoding) -- see also encguide which is linked there